# android jetpack compose textField does not resize screen on API31

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

On API 31
I made scrollable column(not lazyColumn) with TextField.
when i click the textfield at first, the screen is not moving(resized) but when i click again screen is resized.
first time i thought compose version was the problem but it wasn't.

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(500.dp)
        TextField(text = " ", onValueChange = {})
        TextField(text = " ", onValueChange = {})
        TextField(text = " ", onValueChange = {})
}
```

I tried to a API 30, but there is not problem.
is there anyone solved this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by resized? I tried your code on API 31 emulator and focusing and second clicking any TF doesn't do any layout change.

Comment: I meant "adjustResize",  when keyboard comes up